# The optimal way to make Flutter application multilingual

Tags: flutter, dart

There are different ways to make Flutter applications multilingual
For example, putting the translations in the json file and also using the flutter_localizations package, and instead of using json, create an abstract String class for each translation, similar to the code below:

```
class LanguageEn extends Languages {

  @override
  String get appName => "Multi-languages";

  @override
  String get labelWelcome => "Welcome";

  @override
  String get labelSelectLanguage => "Select Language";

  @override
  String get labelInfo => "This is multi-languages demo application";
  
}
```

Which method do you think is optimal and its management is better?

Comment: You absolutely want to use [flutter_localization](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_localization) and .arb templates.  Look here: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization, and Google for tutorials, e.g  https://phrase.com/blog/posts/flutter-localization/

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization its useful for you